# Prevent entering duplicate records in file using Shell Script

Tags: linux, shell, unix, uniq

I am creating one sh file in which user enters the roll number, name, subject name and marks. And i am storing it in one text file. 
Now i don't want the user to enter the same roll number again. If he enters the same roll number it should throw an message. 
Here is what i have done:

```
read -p "Enter the roll: " roll
read -p "Enter the name: " name
read -p "Enter the Subject: " sub
read -p "Enter the mark: " mark
echo "$roll $name $sub $mark" >> asd.txt
```

How to prevent Entering the duplicate roll number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
touch asd.txt
rollExists=1
while [ $rollExists != 0 ]
do
    read -p "Enter the roll: " roll
    rollExists=`grep -e "^${roll} " asd.txt | wc -l`
    if [[ "$rollExists" != "0" ]]
    then
            echo "Roll already exists"
    fi
done
read -p "Enter the name: " name
read -p "Enter the Subject: " sub
read -p "Enter the mark: " mark
echo "$roll $name $sub $mark" >> asd.txt
```

Comment: Instead of piping `grep` to `wc -l` and checking the number of lines, just do `if grep -q -e "^$roll" asd.txt; then ...`

Comment: yes could do, only with a space before the closing quote "^${roll} "

Comment: Thank you so much M.B. Great help